# How can I see the full date with year on macOS Big Sur 11.2.1?

Tags: macos, mac, big-sur, settings

I do NOT see anywhere to add year.

I have looked in every setting in "System Preferences" and just do not see.

Comment: Are you talking about the displayed time at the top right hand corner ? (in the menu bar)

Comment: Yes I am talking about the displayed time at the top right hand corner.

Comment: It is sadly a non-native supported feature on macOS. (But it doesn't mean you won't any app that would make the job !)

Comment: Appreciate confirmation, that stinks!

Comment: Thanks for asking. This will be linked to another question so that more searches get to the answer. +1